# Unable to access friends count for a friend of mine

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I'm trying to get friends count via my [account](https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=XXX) using Facebook API. Its working well.

But if i get friends count using one of my [friendId](https://graph.facebook.com/100002110225990/friends?access_token=XXX), i'm getting the following exception

> Tests in error: 
>  friendsCount(com.company.facebook.test.FbClientTest):
>   Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: (#604) Can't
>   lookup all friends of 649390517. Can only lookup for the logged in
>   user or the logged in user's friends that are users of your app.

Comment: Just a note @amala - you should never post an active access token anywhere.  With that access token and your user_id - people can perform actions on your behalf! *scary*!! - I have removed the access token from your question.

Comment: Just to illustrate my point - this access_token contained **ALL** if not **A LOT** of permissions... Someone could easily do some very nasty stuff with this info... http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17036050/scr166.png

Comment: Thanks a lot @Lix for removing my access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message seems pretty clear, you can't access friends-of-friends via the API unless the other friend also uses your app.

You can however check for mutual friends between your app's user and any arbitrary user ID.

To do that, make an API call to

```
/USER_ID/mutualfriends/OTHER_USER_ID
```

Where USER_ID is the user who's authorised your app, and OTHER_USER_ID is the user you want to check for mutual friends with.